# I can query mysql DB but not save changes to it

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio

I had created a system using Visual Studio 2015 with a SQLServer database, i could query the DB but not save changes to it. So i created the database inside Visual Studio. I now tried to create the database in MySQL workbench and have the same issue. I switched to mysql as i was unsure if i had correctly installed My SQL Server, i have definately installed mysql properly as i have used it for projects in Java. 
I created the database using a code first technique and this worked fine. Any ideas? 
Connection String from appsettings

```
"DataAccessMySqlProvider": "server=localhost;port=3306;database=rentalsdb;userid=root;password=******"
```

In Startup.cs

```
            var sqlConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataAccessMySqlProvider");
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<RentalsDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySQL(
        sqlConnectionString,
        b => b.MigrationsAssembly("RentalsRated.Web")));

        services.AddDbServiceDependencies(sqlConnectionString);
```

In my repo then

```
 public bool CreateUser(UserAccount user)
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            try
            {
                _Context.UserAccounts.Add(user);

                _Context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _Context.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch ....
```

I can see the right variables come to here. It all worked fine with the database in visual studios server explorer. 
Thanks!

IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

The Stack trace:    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(Tuple`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)...

UPDATE: Works when i comment out my data that is being passed as Byte[].

Comment: Do you catch any exception when you call SaveChanges? Please post the details of the exception if so and its stack trace.

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko please see edit above. Thanks

Comment: What happens when you comment out the line which is marking the entity state as Modified and call SaveChanges immediately after call to Add(user)?

Comment: {System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at MySql.Data.Types.MySqlBinary.EscapeByteArray(Byte[] bytes, Int32 length, MySqlPacket packet)
   at MySql.Data.Types.MySqlBinary.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.WriteValue(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, Object val, Int32 length)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.Serialize(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterInde...

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko I see now. Storing the salt and passwords as blob is the issue. What should i use for the column type?

Comment: If your passwords are hashes in Base64 then one of the string types will work better. Have a look to the list of mappings here https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/DataTypeMapping.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause:**
Password and salt fields are defined as blobs. Change the type of the password and salt fields to one of the string types instead.

**Masking issue:**
You were changing the state of the entity to Modifed right after adding it to the table which might corrupt the internal state of the context.

MSDN is recommending two different ways of adding new entity to the context
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx

1) By adding the entity directly to the table.

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blog = new Blog { Name = "ADO.NET Blog" }; 
    context.Blogs.Add(blog); 
    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

2) By changing the state of the entity to Added

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blog = new Blog { Name = "ADO.NET Blog" }; 
    context.Entry(blog).State = EntityState.Added; 
    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to store them as Byte[] then? I have tried binary, varbinary, blob and longblob with no success. It would be making substantial changes to my project to switch to strings at this point. Thanks